# Google Script Event Trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a google script presently that uses the basic time-based triggers, and runs once a day. The code works and the trigger runs when it is supposed to, but I want to enhance my script to run when a file is uploaded to my drive. Right now, I use a lot of logic to determine if any file has been uploaded since the last run, but I really want to get it so that the script runs if a file has been uploaded.

My question is, is that possible, and if so, can someone direct me to some links on how to make this a reality?

Thanks,

Comment: You want to look into the Drive Activity API

Comment: There is no existing apps script trigger that could run your script automatically when a file was uploaded to your drive. But as what was mentioned by @Dmitry Kostyuk you can use [Drive Activity API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive-activity) to check if there is a file uploaded in your dive. You can add additional filter to filter the date time of your last check (when you trigger your script using time-based trigger)